# Where should dependent Services be @Autowired (Controller or Service)?

Tags: spring, service, architecture, autowired

Consider these two following options:

**Option #1:** Autowiring the required Services in Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/foo")
public class FooController {
    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;

    @Autowired
    private BazService bazService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getFoo(...) {
        Foo foo = fooService.getFooInstance(...);

        List<Foo> foos = fooService.getFooList(foo);
        List<Bar> bars = barService.getBarList(foo);
        Baz baz        = bazService.getBaz(foo);

        ...

        return "view/foo/index.jsp";
    }
}
```

**Option #2:** Autowiring dependent Services for UoW in specific Service

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/foo")
public class FooController {
    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getFoo(...) {
        Foo foo = fooService.getFooInstance(...);

        FooDTO fooInfo = fooService.getFooAllInformation(foo);

        List<Foo> foos = fooInfo.getFoos();
        List<Bar> bars = fooInfo.getBars();
        Baz baz        = fooInfo.getBaz();
        ...

        return "view/foo/index.jsp";
    }
}


@Service
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;

    @Autowired
    private BazService bazService;

    ...

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public FooDTO getFooAllInformation(Foo foo) {
        List<Foo> foos = getFooList(foo);
        List<Bar> bars = barService.getBarList(foo);
        Baz baz        = bazService.getBaz(foo);

        ...
    }
}
```

Well, currently I'm using Option #1 and everything's working just fine. But I'm wondering if this approach is good enough or not. Do any of them have any significant advantages over the other one? I should mention that I'm aware of `@Transactional` for the `INSERT` part of the Service (which I have omitted here). But what about just *Reading* the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second option is both cleaner, faster, and safer. It's basically using the facade pattern.

Cleaner because it moves code business code outside of the UI layer, in the service layer, where it belongs.

Faster because, since everything is made in the same transaction, you'll save transaction openings and closings, and benefit from the transactional cache (assuming you use an ORM to fetch the data you need). And it's of course even faster if the UI and service layers are on sepaate JVMs.

Safer because, since everything is in the same transaction, each service will get data from the same consistent database "snapshot". In the first option, you could have the first method return a foo which doesn't exist anymore when the second service is called. Of course, this depends on the transaction isolation level of your database, but it'll always be safer than doing it in several transactions.

Comment: The important thing is that there is a behavioural difference related to transactions. Rollbacks won't work as expected with #1.

Comment: @atamanroman: agreed, but since all these methods start with get, I assumed they were read-only methods, where rollbacks don't matter. That's why I insisted on isolation rather than coherence. But of course, it's even more important to put everything inside a single transactional service method is the methods modify the database.

Comment: @JBNizet @atamanroman Thanks for your responses. I am aware of situation for Inserting the data. But now this raised me another question. `getFooAllInformation` is the starting point for executing the UoW, and it's `@Transactional` of course. Should every other methods being called in it be transactional too? (e.g. `getBarList`, `getBaz`, ...)

Comment: They would be automatically part of the same transaction, since the transaction is started when `getFooAllInformation()` is called. If you plan to call them from a non-transactional method (directly from the presentation layer, for example), then they should probably be annotated with @Transactional, yes.

Comment: @JBNizet You're right. To sum this up, #1 is nearly always a bad idea. A big legacy project I'm working on does it this way which causes massive PITA because rollbacks are only partial and leave inconsistent data. Having all the business code in the UI is a bit less of a problem compared to that.